# postgresql procedure for fetching top 10%,20% and 30% values of the total values

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

i have a table named Scoreboard which contains a field named as score which is an array containing values   `27,56,78,12,89,77,34,23,90,87,33,55,30,67,76,87,56`and i want to write a PostgreSQL procedure to fetch three categories
`category 1 = top 10% values of the total no of values in array`
`category 2 = top 20% values of the total no of values in array`
`category 3 = top 30% values of the total no of values in array`
and put it in an array in the same format i.e
`[category 1 values,category 2 values,category 3 values]`

Answer (score 0):

smth like this should do:

```
t=# with p as (
  with ntile as (
    with v as (
      select unnest('{27,56,78,12,89,77,34,23,90,87,33,55,30,67,76,87,56}'::int[]) a
    )
    select a,ntile(10) over(order by a desc)
    from v
  )
  select distinct  string_agg(a::text,',') over (partition by ntile),ntile
  from ntile
  where ntile <=3 order by ntile
)
select array_agg(concat('category ',ntile,' ',string_agg))
from p;
                         array_agg
------------------------------------------------------------
 {"category 1 90,89","category 2 87,87","category 3 78,77"}
(1 row)

Time: 0.493 ms
```

Comment: Thanks but actually i want it in a procedure plus i forgot to mention that array is in the table so we have to fetch the values from that table

Comment: you can wrap the above to sql function. also please try to ask question from the first try - otherwise we don't answer the question, but rather chatting support here

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming , you have a table with one column as id and another one is an array type. Based on assumption 
I have created table as below and inserted two values to it.

```
create table test_array (id int, values int[]);
insert into test_array values(1 ,'{27,56,78,12,89,77,34,23,90,87,33,55,30,67,76,87,56}' );
insert into test_array values(2 ,'{72,65,84,21,98,77,43,32,9,78,41,66,3,76,67,88,56}' );
```

Below is function which is used to find category as mentioned by you. If you do not have any id column in your table
then you can add number by using [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html) hint: row_number().

```
create or replace function find_category() returns table(category text[]) as 
$$
BEGIN

return query with unnestColumn as (
select id, unnest(values) as values, ntile(10) over(partition by id order by unnest(values) desc) as ntilenumber
from test_array 
) ,groupedCategory as ( select id, ntilenumber, string_agg(values::text,',') as combinedvalues from unnestColumn 
where 
ntilenumber <= 3 
group by id, ntilenumber ) 
select array_agg(concat('Categoty',ntilenumber, ' ', combinedvalues ))
from groupedCategory
group by id;

END;
$$
language 'plpgsql';
```

Execute below function to check output.

```
select * from find_category();
```